# How to share Angular MFE's secondary entry point with other remote apps

Tags: micro-frontend, angular13

We are facing an issue with respect to Angular MFE's secondary entry point.

The code base structure as below:

```
my-app
|---------apps
           |-----shell
           |-----mfe1

|---------libs
          |----libA
               |-----src
               |-----secondaryEntryPoint1
                     |----ng-package.json
                     |----src
               |-----secondaryEntryPoint2
                     |----ng-package.json
                     |----src
```

We have included the libA as sharedMappings in the webpack.config of both shell and mfe1 app as well these paths are referenced in tsconfig.base.json.  The lib is referenced as @myapp/libA/secondaryEntryPoint1 -- **This is not referred as Singleton.**

We have also tried adding the shared mapping in the webpack by passing the below properties:

```
version,
import - (path to the respective index file)
includeSecondaries: true
```

As shown in the image:
[Shared object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XgUg7.png)

The above approach was also not working as expected and the secondary-entrypoints are initialised multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

you need to share each secondary entry point explicitly in the webpack config.

If you go with @angular-architects/module-federation, you can also set

[1] https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-architects/module-federation#user-content-share-helper

Comment: The mentioned link no longer points to the correct location, can you update it to the correct location?